# MySQL query with 2 COUNT() of other tables with where conditions

Tags: mysql

I've a table called sports that contains a list of list of sports, other called seasons that contains the seasons for a specific sport and competitions that have the competitions of a specific sport and season.

I need one MySQL query to print the list of sports with how much seasons and competitions has each. My tables structure:

**sports**

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name               | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug               | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description        | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**seasons**

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_sport           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name               | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug               | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**competitions**

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_season          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name               | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug               | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description        | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The result of my query needs to contain: sports.*, total_seasons (SUM of seasons where seasons.id_sport=sports.id) and total_competitions (SUM of competitions where competitions.id_season=seasons.id AND seasons.id_sport=sports.id).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please confirm something...  The seasons can have multiple sports simultaneously overlapping... correct?

Comment: @DRapp: Each sport creates seasons. They are not shared between sports. So football will have season 2010-2011 with id=1 and id_sport=1 and soccer season 2010-2011 with id=2 and id_sport=2, for example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use left join instead of inner join

```
select
  sports.id,
  sports.name,
  sports.slug,
  sports.description,
  ifnull(count( distinct seasons.id ), 0) as DistinctSeasons,
  ifnull(count( distinct competitions.id ), 0) as TotalCompetitions
from 
  sports
  left join seasons on sports.id=seasons.id_sport
  left join competitions on seasons.id = competitions.id_season
group by
  sports.id;
```

Comment: It's all fine but I get TotalCompetitions as 1 when there is no season for a competition. If there is no season can't be a competition. How can I fix it? Thank you in advance, it works fine but only this detail! Happy new year!

Comment: @Isern Palaus - the problem is caused by the use of asterisk, the update version should help (or does not ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sports.*,
    COUNT(seasons.id) AS total_seasons,
    COUNT(competitions.id) AS total_competitions
    FROM sports, seasons, competitions
    WHERE sports.id=id_sport AND seasons.id=id_season
    GROUP BY sports.id
```

Comment: Thank you Borealid but the same I've commented to DRapp. If some sport don't have competition or season I don get the result. How can I solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select
      sports.id,
      sports.name,
      sports.slug,
      sports.description,
      count( distinct seasons.id ) as DistinctSeasons,
      count( * ) as TotalCompetitions
   from 
      sports 
         left outer join Seasons
            on sports.id = seasons.id_sport,
         left outer join Competitions
            on seasons.id = Competitions.id_season
   group by
      sports.id
```

Comment: Thank you DRapp, but I don't understand why if some of the sports don't have a season or competition I don't have result for that. How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: @Isern Palaus, I changed my version to left outer join as suggested by @ajreal, but his version also includes check if no such matching to wrap the counting within IFNULL()...  So if there are no such matchings, you will get a zero value instead of NULL in the result set.